# How to handle iframe in particular situation. How to handle iframe contents?

Tags: html, iframe

i have created search box same as usual search engine have and down to that i have used iframes and given google address to that frame. I want method to search in google by typing in upper box only. OR such a method that even if I search in google directly in iframe then the searching terms should appear on upper box.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are trying to do Cross Site scripting using iframe. The method you choose is not supported by almost all modern browser.

Instead if you want to implement google search in your website, to search content within your site. I'll recommend following code

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search">
    <h5>Search</h5>
    <input name="q" type="text">
    <input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="stackoverflow.com">
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Go" />
</form>
```

The above code on search take user to google but search result show only within stackoverflow.com (you can change this with your website address) and on clicking any search result user will come back to your site.

Comment: I have created simple box like search engines usually have. Below that I have used iframe...OK. In iframe I have given link of google.com. Means whenever I open my website that google page will open.                                                                                                          1. I just want to get contents what is typed in search box of google in iframe and automatically paste that content in upper box.                        2. Also the content what is typed in upper box should appear below in google search box automatically. I don't want results. HELP